# Rename all files in directory?

Tags: ruby, file, rename

My task:

> Write a program to rename files using regular expressions. This
>   program will take three command line arguments: the directory in which
>   to rename files, a regular expression that matches files to be
>   renamed, and a string to replace the regular expression match.  The
>   primary use is to change file extensions, but it should be able to
>   handle replacing any portion of the file name.It should run as
>   follows:

```
./fixname.rb dir 'pattern' replacement
```

The program I have written is:

```
puts "Renaming files..."


folder_path = ARGV[0]
reg_exp = ARGV[1].to_regexp

Dir.glob(folder_path + "/*").sort.each do |f|
    filename = File.basename(f, File.extname(f))
  myString = String.new 
  myString = filename 
  filename = myString.gsub(reg_exp, ARGV[2])
  #puts myString
    File.rename(f, folder_path + "/" + filename + File.extname(f))
end

puts "Renaming complete."
```

The rename doesn't happen when I am using regexp, otherwise it is working. I'm getting:

```
error "`gsub': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)"
```

Comment: I'm not gonna do your homework.

Comment: You should be able to find everything you need here: [link](http://www.google.com)

Comment: If you honestly start the work yourself, and get stuck somehow, then ask a new question: Post the code you have so far with an explanation of what you don't understand, and it is very likely you will get help here. So you can still get help with your homework, just not have it all done for you in one go.

Comment: how to write filename[reg_exp] = ARGV[2].

Comment: @user3497652: Thank you for the edit. Could you explain what is going wrong? It looks like the script kind-of works, but maybe the rename doesn't happen when you use regexp syntax (you are doing an exact-match replace). Correct?

Comment: yes rename doesnt happen when i am using regexp. otherwise it is working.Regexp was entered through command line argument

Comment: I've edited that in - feel free to correct anything I have done wrong. You have some reopen votes already, and I think a clearer title plus what you just commented about your problem will get this off hold and someone can answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you think is a regex is not, it's a String containing a regex pattern.

You need to convert that to a Regexp object. How to do that is left to you.

Comment: i have done changed like this.  reg_exp = ARGV[1].to_regexp. Is that ok?

Comment: You tell us. Is there a "String.to_regexp" method?

Comment: Then perhaps you'd like to take on that task? The OP asked a very easily answered question, that would have only take a few minutes to have found the answer via a simple search. Sometimes the best answer is to put them on the correct path and let them continue on. Answers aren't always giving them code, good answers teach them how to figure out the problem so they can apply what they've learned to other, similar, situations. That's what I did. In addition, the OP was doing a homework-type assignment. It's up to them to answer the question and they should do it without help from others.